# "interacts with" at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar

I would like to ask help about the following sentences. I am not sure which of them are correct and which of them are wrong. It is not a school assignment, I just couldn't decide which of them is the best.

1. Andrew notifies the admin about the software the user interacts with.
2. Andrew notifies the admin about the software that the user interacts with.
3. Andrew notifies the admin about the software the user is interacting with.
4. Andrew notifies the admin about the software that the user is interacting with.
5. Andrew notifies the admin about the software that user interacts with.
6. Andrew notifies the admin about the software that user is interacting with.

Thanks!

Comment: In the complex sentenses like these you can always skip conjunction "that".

Comment: @HotLicks May I know if you have a better way to express the sentences above?

Comment: @Katherina May I ask which sentence do you prefer?

Comment: Andrew notifies the admin about the software with which the user interacts

Comment: Is 'interacts with' really preferable to 'uses'? Even if 'user' is replaced with say 'client', 'customer' ...?

Comment: Hi @Edwin, yes it seems. For example, I am enabling/disabling Google Chrome's extensions, so I am not really using it to browse the web.

Comment: I'd say 'interacts with' is also too general for those examples. 'Enabling / disabling' seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find grammar prescriptive-ists that say, "You should never end a sentence with a preposition," but it's easy to find widely respected grammarians that disagree with this idea and even go so far as to [call it a grammar myth](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition).

> I know many of you were taught that you shouldn’t end a sentence with
>   a preposition, but it’s a myth. In fact, I consider it one of the top
>   ten grammar myths because many people believe it’s true, but nearly
>   all grammarians disagree, at least in some cases.

But, in the case of your proposed sentences, the total phrasing is awkward and the ending preposition contributes to that awkwardness. If your usage is semi-formal or formal, you can try:

"Andrew notifies the admin about the software with which the user is interacting."

or you could try:

"Andrew notifies the admin about which software is receiving user interaction."

Comment: Following the preposition rule is a proscription up with which I will not put.

Comment: Your second sentence has a different connotation to me. It means that Andrew merely identifies which software is receiving interaction, rather than talking about the software in a more general way (e.g. passing on problem reports).

Comment: @Barmar I agree. I found the sentence awkward and couldn't, exactly, determine the intended meaning. That's why offered alternatives.

Comment: Hello, aside from being awkward, are those sentences grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @user1764381 I contend that there is no such thing as "incorrect" and "correct" grammar. There is "poor" grammar (awkward and hard to understand) and there is excellent grammar (easy to understand). It is a spectrum of the quality of your communication. Technically speaking, your sentence is "incorrect" according to prescriptive-ist grammarians, but I don't agree with their point of view.